# Simple Word Arithmetic?

Tags: java, math, logic, cpu-word, addition

```
package pls;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int amount;
        int amount2;
        int[] Array = new int[100];
        int[] Array1 = new int[100];
        int total;
        char b;
        String bad = "";
        String finalA = "";
        System.out.println("Input your first word/letter (must be upper case): ");
        String first = keyboard.next();
        amount = first.length();
        System.out.println("Input your second word/letter (must be upper case): ");
        String second = keyboard.next();
        amount2 = second.length();

        while (amount < amount2)//to add on 'A' to first word
        {
        first = 'A' + first;
        amount++;
        }

        while (amount2 < amount)//to add on 'A' to second word
        {
        second = 'A' + second;
        amount2++;  
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            Array[i] = (int)first.charAt(i) - 65;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < amount2; i++) {
            Array1[i] = (int)second.charAt(i) - 65;
        }

        for (int i = amount; i >= 0; i--) {
            total = Array[amount] + Array1[amount2];    

                if (total > 25) {
                    int pls = total % 26;
                    b = (char)(pls + 65);
                    finalA = b + finalA;
                    total = total / 26;
                    b = (char)(total + 65);
                    finalA = b + finalA;
                    total = pls + total;
                    b = (char)(total + 65);
                    finalA = b + finalA;

                }
                else {
                    b = (char)(total + 65);
                    finalA = b + finalA;
                }
                amount--;
                amount2--;
                }

        finalA = finalA.substring(0, finalA.length()-1);

        while (finalA.charAt(0) == 'A') {
            finalA = finalA.substring(0, 0) + finalA.substring(0 + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(finalA);
    }       
    }
```

I need to make a program that lets users add words going from right to left.. They're given numerical values and through that, you can add them. Here are a few examples: CAT & DOG make FOZ, MOM & DAD make POP, ABA & A make BA, BCD & BC make BDF.

Now up to this point, I've managed to make it work, however this next one screws me up... ZZZ + ZZZ = BZZY.. This is how this part of the program is explained: "For example, Z + Z = BY (since Z + Z = 50, and 50 modulo 26 is 24, which is Y, and the carry is the quotient you get when you divide 50 by 26, i.e. 1, which represents B)." I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!(Code at the top because errors.)

Comment: When you have a carry, you have to save the carry for the _next_ iteration of the loop, and add it into the total.  Try adding 999 + 888 by hand, with pencil and paper, the way they taught you to do it when you were 6 or 7.  I think you'll see what I mean--in the tens place, you have to add 1 + 9 + 8.  (I **hope** they taught you how to do arithmetic...  I don't always know what they're teaching in schools these days.)

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, you only need to create one character per pass, the one calculated with the mod operator.

The other calculation should store the division as the carry.

The total has to include both letters and the carry from the previous calculation.

You do NOT have to remove the last character of finalA when you are done.